# find which system is transmitting through a particular port

Tags: networking, monitoring, command

I am using command `nc -lu <port no.>` to find on given port any data is receiving or not. I am getting data if there is transmission going on (but don't know from where!). Is there any way that should provide me the transmitters IP address??
`wireshark` and `nmap` are there, but I want a shorter way, if possible.
**UPDATED:** I think `nc -luv` is what I want, But at a time it is showing only one IP. I want to know if more than one system is transmitting through that port??

Comment: `netstat` not available?

Comment: how to do with `netstat`?

Comment: you could use strace against the pid of nc to trace system calls like connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the answers posted so far. Here are some other options:

Add the `-v` option to nc. This will show (only!) the first source address that a UDP packet is received from.

Also, `netstat -nu` seems to have some connection-ish state information for UDP conversations.

Comment: Gr8... Thanks but see updated Question.

Answer (score 5):

if the application uses a specific protocol, you can use a ngrep (for package inspection ) or a tcpdump (for port/host tracking). This is useful specially on a router or a proxy or DNS (if you can map the app to a hostname) to track the usage.

example for ssh:

```
ngrep SSH-2.0
```

or access to site, via dns (DNS can be cached, but on a long run you can see who is using it)

```
ngrep bad.site.org port 53
```

or via ip connections:

```
tcpdump host bad.site.org
```

Finally, you can use the nmap with the -A option, to help map the port to a specific protocol:

```
nmap -A 192.168.0.0/16 -p 8000-9000  2>/dev/null | grep "Interesting ports on\|open"
```

this will show the IP, open ports and the protocol/service if nmap manage to identify it

Answer (score 3):

If the application uses a specific network port, `nmap` is your friend.

If not, you need to have some sort of monitoring or deployment software, or you need to run a script on each server to find what is installed and what is running. Example:

```
ssh servername 'ps -ef|grep appname|grep -v grep'
```

will show you if the app is actually running.

Comment: please go through updated Question.

Comment: please see updated answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Run your nc command in background : nc -lu  &

use lsof to see the network sockets used by nc.

```
lsof -i4 -n | grep ^nc
```

and then type :

```
watch -n 1 "lsof -i4 -n | grep ^nc"
```

Watch will re-run the command every second (it is not as accurate as wireshark) :

```
Every 1.0s: lsof -i4 -n | grep ^nc                                                                                        

nc        29033 user    3u  IPv4 4638215      0t0  UDP *:5007
nc        29469 user    3u  IPv4 4641772      0t0  UDP src_ip:46805->dest_ip:5007
```

Answer (score 2):

I have another idea which I just used for a similar purpose:

Add a rule to your iptables :

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport <PORT_TO_MONITOR> -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "new_connection " --log-level 7
```

This will add a line to your system log for each new connection to that port.

You can also redirect this to a seperate log file, I believe.